# Extract type information from a Python project using Pyright?

Tags: python, types, language-server-protocol, pyright, program-analysis

I have to analyze Python codebase programatically and need to extract type information for variables. I'm interested in using **Pyright**.

Is there a way to programmatically use **Pyright** to analyze Python code and retrieve type information?

What I've considered so far:

**Language Server Protocol (LSP):**
As Pyright is an a language server, I presume I can set up an LSP client. Then I can start the Pylance language server, and then sending LSP requests to get type information. However, I'm unsure about the specifics of this approach.

**Example:**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def get_age(self) -> int:
        return self.age

def add_numbers(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

def main():
    # Create a Person object
    person = Person("Alice", 30)
    
    # Invoke get_age method and print the result
    age = person.get_age()
    print(f"{person.name}'s age is {age} years old.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For the line `age = person.get_age()`, for `person` variable, I want to know that it of type `Person`. I have to do this programmatically.

Has anyone attempted something similar or have insights on how to achieve this? Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!